# Prove if $P(A \cup B) \le P(A \cap B)$, then $P(A) = P(B)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am unsure if my thought process for proving this inequality is correct. This is what I have so far:
$$
P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) ≤ P(A \cap B)
$$
$$
P(A) + P(B) \le 2  P(A \cap B)
$$
$$
P(A) + P(B) \le 2 P(A) P(B)
$$
and in order for the last line to be possible, $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ have to be $0$, thus $P(A) = P(B)$. This doesn't seem right because I feel like there should be more cases than just $0$ for this inequality to be true and I was wondering if anyone could help guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Please update you question by formatting equations with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I did a couple for you to get started.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson Thank you! I have updated the rest of the post.

Comment: It is not true in general that $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$. That holds if and only if $A$ and $B$ are independent. Moreover, even if it were true, $P(A) + P(B) \leq 2P(A)P(B)$ would not imply $P(A)=P(B)=0$.

Comment: +1, taking your question from $-2$ to $-1$.  I am very surprised that mathSE reviewers downvoted your question, given that you clearly showed work.  In evaluating your question, the fact that your analysis is incomplete or has an error is (in my opinion) irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editing added to the very end of my answer, where I disagree with the comment of Zhanxiong, which follows my answer.

---

Starting with your first equation, you **also** have that 
$p(A) \geq p(A \cap B)$ and $p(B) \geq p(A \cap B)$. 
Therefore, $p(A) + p(B) \geq 2 p(A\cap B).$

Therefore, you can now conclude that $p(A) + p(B) = 2p(A \cap B)$.

The only way that this is possible is if 
$p(A) = p(A\cap B)$ and $p(B) = p(A\cap B)$.

**Edit**
Thanks to Zhanxiong (re comment below) for catching my mistaken conclusion that the above implies that $A \subseteq B$ and that $B\subseteq A.$

Fortunately, that mistaken conclusion is unnecessary to complete the analysis.

Since $p(A) = p(A \cap B) = p(B)$ 
you have that $p(A) = p(B).$

---

**Edit**
On second thought, I disagree with the comment of Zhanxiong, following my answer.

That is, clearly $p(A) = p(A\cap B) + p(A \cap [B^c])$, 
where $B^c$ represents the complement of $B$. 
 Thus, if $p(A) = p(A\cap B)$, then $p(A \cap [B^c])$ must $ = 0.$ 
This implies that $A$ and $B^c$ are disjoint, which implies that $A \subseteq B.$

**Rebuttal from Zhanxiong** 
A basic fact in probability, $P(E)=0$ does not imply $E$ is an empty set.

Comment: The last paragraph of reasoning is redundant (and potentially false), it's unclear to conclude "$B \subset A$" and "$A \subset B$" from $P(A) = P(A \cap B)$, etc. You can stop at "$P(A) = P(A \cap B)$ and $P(B) = P(A \cap B)$".

Comment: @Zhanxiong Very good catch, thanks for the assist.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: @Zhanxiong On second thought, at the risk of compounding my original mistake, I disagree that my original assertion is potential false.  See the 2nd edit that I just added to the end of my answer.  Please advise if I am making an analytical mistake.

Comment: A basic fact in probability, $P(E) = 0$ does not imply $E$ is an empty set. Are you aware of this?

Comment: @Zhanxiong Good rebuttal.  I wasn't aware of this.  I will (again) edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** See [Amit's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4179864/427810) instead for a quicker proof using the same idea.

---

**Hint.** We always have $P(A \cap B) \le P(A \cup B)$ since $A \cap B \subseteq A \cup B$.
Thus, your hypothesis tells us that $P(A \cup B) = P(A \cap B)$. As you have noted, inclusion-exclusion gives us $$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B).$$
Thus, we get $$2P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B).$$
We can rewrite this as $$[P(A \cup B) - P(A)] + [P(A \cup B) - P(B)] = 0.$$
Do you see that both the $[\cdots]$ terms are non-negative? What can we say now?

Answer (score 4):

Since $A \cap B \subseteq A \subseteq A \cup B$, we have $P(A\cap B) \leq P(A) \leq P(A\cup B)$. The two extreme quantities are equal (Why?), so $P(A)$ must be equal to these too. A similar argument works out for $P(B)$.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, no exclusion-inclusion formula is needed. Just use
\begin{align*}
& P(A) \leq P(A \cup B) \leq P(A \cap B) \leq P(B), \\
& P(B) \leq P(A \cup B) \leq P(A \cap B) \leq P(A)
\end{align*}
gives you $P(A) = P(B)$.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach from the others: we have the identity

$$A\cup B = (A\cap B) \cup (A\triangle B)$$

where $A\triangle B = (A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$ - this is called the symmetric difference of the sets. Draw it on a Venn diagram to see why it has this name if you're unsure. One very nice aspect here is that $A\cap B$ and $A\triangle B$ are actually mutually distinct, i.e. their intersection is empty. This is also true for the two individual pieces in the symmetric difference, i.e. $A\setminus B$ and $B\setminus A$. This allows you then to say that

$$ P(A\cup B) = P((A\cap B)\cup(A\triangle B)) = P(A\cap B) + P(A\triangle B).$$

We have not yet invoked your inequality. Let's do that now. From your inequality, we have that

$$ P(A\cup B) \le P(A\cap B) \Longrightarrow P(A\cap B) + P(A\triangle B) \le P(A\cap B). $$

Notice the appearance of $P(A\cap B)$ on both sides. Eliminating it gives us that

$$ P(A\triangle B) = 0. $$

This then tells us that $P(A\cup B) = P(A\cap B)$, however $P(A) \le P(A\cup B)$ and $P(A\cap B)\le P(A)$, so $P(A) \le P(A\cup B) = P(A\cap B) \le P(A)$ so that $P(A) = P(A\cup B) = P(A\cap B)$. Similar for $B$ which gives you equality between $P(A)$ and $P(B)$.

Comment: $P(C) = 0$ does not imply that $C = \emptyset$, only that it is of probability $0$. The argument could be fixed by saying that $P(A) = P(A \cup (A \triangle B)) = P(A \cup B)$ and using a similar argument for $B$ as well.

Comment: Oh I was for some reason assuming a measure space with no non-empty null sets (like baby probability), but you're absolutely right. Let me fix it.